# arcpy.da.UpdateCursor error: RuntimeError: create cursor has failed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor

I'm trying to delete a few rows in the output table that is created using the Compare Table tool (anything that has an ObjectID < 0). My script was working fine (i.e. it produced the table compare output), until I inserted this Update Cursor code. It's throwing me a `RuntimeError: create cursor has failed` error. I tested a Search cursor in its place, and that worked fine. I'm thinking there may be a lock of some sort on the data since it was just created, but I'm not sure how to clear that lock. Any ideas?

```
arcpy.TableCompare_management(orig_queryTable, arcgisTable_cleaned, "UNIQUE_ID", "ATTRIBUTES_ONLY", "IGNORE_SUBTYPES", "", "", "CONTINUE_COMPARE", out_compare_file=compareTxtFile)

sqlExp = """ "ObjectID" < 0 """
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(compareTxtFile, "ObjectID", sqlExp) as deleteCursor:
    for row in deleteCursor:
        deleteCursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: I think deleteRow() doesn't take an argument, so you can just write `deleteCursor.deleteRow()` rather than `deleteCursor.deleteRow(row)`.

Comment: John is correct.  Also, why not use the `'OID@'` token to grab the ObjectID field?  It will always find it by its type (OID).

Comment: I edited the question to remove the row from (row) (but the script still throws the same error). As for the ObjectID field, it's not the actual OID field. It's a field that references the tables' being compared ObjectID's so that you can perform a join back to the original data. It's actually just a "long" field. In the output, the "real" OID field created is called "OBJECTID_1." It's a little confusing.

Comment: @KristenG. Are you running the UpdateCursor on a standalone text file?

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question so that it contains a snippet that works up to the point where the error is thrown (i.e. starts with `import arcpy`) and the exact wording (including line number) of that error, please?

Comment: @PolyGeo The problem was definitely what artwork21 answered below. It was because I was trying to use an UpdateCursor on a text file. It works now. I used arcpy.TableToTable_conversion to convert the text file to an ArcGIS table. The only reason I didn't include the entire code above is because it's quite huge, I know it works otherwise without the above lines of code, and there's too much confidential info in it. It'd take a long time to remove all of that stuff and still have it make sense. Do you have any other suggestions for how I can edit the question to make it more readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is you cannot use updateCursor on a text file to delete reocrds.  Try using it against a dbBASE or geodatabase table instead.

Comment: I think you're right. I realized that a bit ago and have been messing with my code. I'm using arcpy.TableToTable_conversion to convert it to a gdb table, exactly like you're proposing.